# Where can one find how long a cease fire has left?

Tags: civilization-5

When one enters into a peace treaty, there is a period of time where the player cannot go to war with the other civilization.   At some point this cease fire period ends and the civilizations may go back to war with one another.

The issue I have is that I cannot find on the interface where to see how many more turns are left until the end of a cease fire.

Can someone tell me where to find the remaining turns on a cease-fire on the interface?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to **Diplomacy Overview -> Deal History**. All your current peace treaties should be listed there, along with (1) their duration and (2) their starting turn. That means you can easily find out the remaining turns via `[duration] - ([current turn] - [start turn])` (a negative value means it has expired).

RE: your comment on the other answer, since the Fall 2012 patch, peace treaty duration depends only on game speed:

- Quick - 10 turns
- Normal - 10 turns
- Epic - 15 turns
- Marathon - 30 turns

Comment: as normal Oak has the best answers

Answer (score 1):

Cease fire peace treaty's last 10 turns.  You should receive an alert on the right hand side of your screen when the cease fire period is over.

Another way you can check is via the diplomacy menu. If you click on a civilization and the 'Delcare War' option is grayed out then you are still during a treaty period.

I know there are other ways, possibly using the world icon in the top right of your screen that lists all the civilizations but that is all I can answer for now.  I will test this and complete my answer.

Comment: Is it always 10 turns no matter the game speed?

Comment: I can confirm that peace treaties are listed in current deals list in diplomacy overview.